# I'm having trouble putting together a system that creates a receipt

Tags: c#, textbox

I have been given a coding assignment by my recruiter for a job as a junior developer. There were three choices and I went with a problem that requires calculating a purchase. All items are supposed be taxed 10% unless they are books, food or medicine. Anything imported is taxed an extra 5%, even if they are tax exempt. So I created a form that allows a user to type in the name of the item, two check boxes for whether they are imported or tax exempt, a textbox for inputing price, and a text box for each input. Underneath is a textbox that is supposed to calculate the total sales tax, underneath that is a textbox for the total. The first checkbox is named "Item1Import" the next one is called "Item1Exempt." The price text box is named "Item1Price" and the other "Item1Output." And for each item the number would change, Item2Import, Item3Import, etc. The last two textboxes are called "SalesTax" and "Total."

Here is the code I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


        private void Item1Price_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(Item1Exempt.Checked && Item1Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item1Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text) * 0.05).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else if(Item1Exempt.Checked && !Item1Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item1Output.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text)).ToString("C2");
                }
                else if(!Item1Exempt.Checked && Item1Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item1Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text) * 0.1) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text) * 0.05)).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Item1Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text) * 0.1)).ToString("C2");
                }

            }

        private void Item2Price_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Item2Exempt.Checked && Item2Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item2Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text) * 0.05).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else if (Item2Exempt.Checked && !Item2Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item2Output.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text)).ToString("C2");
                }
                else if (!Item2Exempt.Checked && Item2Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item2Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text) * 0.1) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text) * 0.05)).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Item2Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text) * 0.1)).ToString("C2");
                }
            }

        private void Item3Price_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Item3Exempt.Checked && Item3Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item3Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text) * 0.05).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else if (Item3Exempt.Checked && !Item3Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item3Output.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text)).ToString("C2");
                }
                else if (!Item3Exempt.Checked && Item3Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item3Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text) * 0.1) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text) * 0.05)).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Item3Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text) * 0.1)).ToString("C2");
                }
            }

        private void Item4Price_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Item4Exempt.Checked && Item4Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item4Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text) * 0.05).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else if (Item4Exempt.Checked && !Item4Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item4Output.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text)).ToString("C2");
                }
                else if (!Item4Exempt.Checked && Item4Import.Checked)
                {
                    Item4Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text) * 0.1) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text) * 0.05)).ToString("C2"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Item4Output.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text) * 0.1)).ToString("C2");
                }
            }

        private void SalesTax_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SalesTax.Text = (((Convert.ToInt32(Item1Output.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(Item1Price.Text)) + ((Convert.ToInt32(Item2Output.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(Item2Price.Text)) + ((Convert.ToInt32(Item3Output.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(Item3Price.Text)) + ((Convert.ToInt32(Item4Output.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(Item4Price.Text)).ToString("C2"));
            }

        private void Total_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Total.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(Item1Output)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Output)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Output)) + (Convert.ToInt32(Item1Output)).ToString("C2"));
            }

    }
}
```

The first problem I'm having is whenever I do type into Item1Price, it outputs to Item1Output but it doesn't work with the others, and the "salestax" and "total" textboxes don't show anything either.

The second problem is I can't type a number like "O.OO" but I can do "00" and whenever I delete the number, it crashes.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will this company provide you with a mentor?

Comment: Having the same code pasted in at four different places will probably not impress any potential employer.

Comment: This code is very messy. Can you please try to clean it up, specify the question, give us an exception message or similar and repost?

Comment: you have to clean up your question, its to messy to read or try to understand... ask little part of your problem not all of it, i suggest you to delete this question and ask some part of your problem again. not all project,taxes etc etc...

Comment: Hot tip, if you ever have to write the same piece of code multiple times, create a separate method and just pass in the required value/s and get the returned result/s. Re-usability and encapsulation are the key words here.

Comment: Yes the company was gonna provide me with a mentor, yes the code is very messy and I should study a bit more. Also I didn't get the job, the position has been filled before I even got a chance to submit it. Thank you guys for your help. Hopefully I'll be able to do better next time.

Answer (score 0):

First thing its not in good fashion to post coding assignment in a forum to get help with for a job.  If you cant complete the coding assignment by yourself I would suggest you reevaluate your skills and ask yourself if your ready for the position that you're trying to obtain.  With that said I remember the days in my beginning when I was going after those positions I probably had no business being in at the time so I can sympathize with that.  Now to your code.

First of all, you need to surround your conversions in a try catch block, the reason your application is crashing is because 0.00 will not convert into a integer since there is a decimal there. 00 will work but when you delete them your textbox.text value is now nothing which is not going to convert either and your program will crash. So you will need to add logic to handle an empty string value and not do a conversion.  I would suggest you use decimal datatype when dealing with money values. As suggested also I would create a method in which you could pass the check box values and return a string value back to set your textbox values. This could clean up your event handler code cause it seems your calculations are the same.